# Is there a Antivirus called "Application level antivirus"

Tags: appsec, antivirus

Recently I heard the term called application level antivirus. I just wanted to know is there anything like that. I heard a company provides such kind of antivirus(I dont want to post company name) I didnt get any reference as such in google. except link to the same company.

Suggestions/inputs please.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking about. You want to know if it exists, but you already found a company doing it. What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

If I look at google for "application level antivirus" I only get to a site which looks like a scam site, i.e. full of references with logos similar to NASA, HP, Comodo etc which don't point to these sites but instead try to sell you something. If you mean the same site then I would recommend hands off.

Comment: I am referring to the same site. Thanks for the comment.. :)